# Different behavior when using InMemorySagaRepositoryProvider vs MongoDbRepository with MassTransit

Tags: c#, masstransit

I experience a different behavior when I change from

```
x.SetInMemorySagaRepositoryProvider();
```

to

```
  x.AddSagaStateMachine<FormRequestStateMachine, FormRequestState>()
                .MongoDbRepository<FormRequestState>(r =>
                {
                    r.Connection = "mongodb://admin:SOMEPASSWORD@127.0.0.1";
                    r.DatabaseName = $"public@tenants@{tenant.Id}";
                    r.CollectionName = "FormRequestState";
                });
```

In my state machine

```
Initially(
            When(CreateNewRequest)
                .Then(x =>
                {
                    x.Publish(new GenerateMagicLink() { CorrelationId = x.Message.CorrelationId });
                }).TransitionTo(Created));
  During(Created,
 When(GenerateMagicLink)
                .Then(x =>
                {
                    x.Saga.MagicLink = new Guid().ToString();
                }));
```

This piece of code work for in memory, but not for the Mongo implementation.
Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the difference between pessimistic concurrency, and optimistic concurrency. To help you out, you should *always* use the in-memory outbox when dealing with sagas, combined with message retry. It's all in the documentation, but essentially:

```cs
cfg.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Interval(100,500,1000,5000));
cfg.UseInMemoryOutbox();
```

This will ensure that your messages are not produced until the saga is properly saved to MongoDB.

> The in-memory saga repository only supports pessimistic locking.

Comment: Thanks Chris for pointing me in the right direction.
I already had the retry, but not the InMemoryOutbox.